# Asymptotical equidistribution of index $p$ subgroups of $\mathbb Z^2$ on the unit tangent bundle of the modular curve

Tags: nt.number-theory, moduli-spaces, lattices, equidistribution

Given a prime $p$ we get $p+1$ sublattices of index $p$ in $\mathbb Z^2$ (identified with $\mathbb Z[i]\subset \mathbb C$) which correspond to some points on the moduli space of such
lattices up to orientation preserving similitudes. One can ask if the set of all such points on the modular curve is asymptotically equidistributed on the modular curve (i.e. if the proportion of such points on an open set $\mathcal O$ of the modular curve $\mathcal M$ is asymptotically equal to the (suitably normalized) area of $\mathcal O$).

I am interested in references and in the following refinement:
The moduli space of lattices only up to rescalings is the quotient
of the unit tantent bundle of $\mathcal M$ by the automorphism group of the underlying lattice (which is $\pm 1$ except at the two conical singularities corresponding to the square lattice and
the regular hexagonal lattice). This space has also a natural
probability measure:

*Question: Is the set of all lattices of prime-index $p$ in $\mathbb Z^2$
asymptotically equidistributed on the above quotient of the unit tangent bundle of the modular curve?*